# Can I dynamically change data annotation value from code?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I have a model that has several fields. Each field has the data annotation:

```
[Display(AutoGeneratedField=false)]
```

I would like to be able to dynamically change that to true via code. Is this possible?

The goal is to be able to show only selected fields in the resulting grid.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use separate view models? Typically you would create view model per view, not one for multiple views and than play with fields visibility. Unless its absolutely necessary.

By the way another way to do it is to use `[ScaffoldColumn(false)]`.

Another by the way - did you try [fluent validation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com)? Don't have much first hand experience with it, but heard its much more robust and flexible than data annotations. I am sure you can express your wishes in fluent validation easier.

Hope that helps & let me know if not.